# DUPLICATE_VALUE error message in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, dmlexception

I have a Visualforce page with a unique custom field. When I try to simulate the error (putting a duplicate value), it is not displayed on the page, I can see it on the developer console, but it looks like it's not rendered on the page, like the other errors.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you have `apex:messages` on the visualforce page?

Comment: Yes, all other messages work just fine!!

Comment: Strange... Maybe try to use `field.addError(String)`